# Conversion of bases with logarithms

Tags: logarithms

The question says if $\log_6(2)$ is $a$ and $\log_5(3)$ is $b$, express $\log_5(2)$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.

I have tried the change of base formula for $ab$ to no avail, can someone give me a hint to get started, and the solution, hidden behind a spoiler tag, if I get stuck? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Write down the expressions for $a$ and $b$ and define your target as $c$: $$a=\log_6(2)=\frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(6)}$$
$$b=\log_5(3)=\frac{\ln(3)}{\ln(5)}$$
$$c=\log_5(2)=\frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(5)}$$
Now use $\ln(6) = \ln(2) + \ln(3)$ and get
$$c=\frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(5)} = \frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(6)} \frac{\ln(6)}{\ln(5)}
=\frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(6)} \frac{\ln(2)+\ln(3)}{\ln(5)}$$
$$c= \frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(6)} \frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(5)} + \frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(6)} \frac{\ln(3)}{\ln(5)}=ac + a b$$
Now solve for $c$ and get the **solution**
$$c=\frac{ab}{1-a}\cdot$$ 
And to be sure you can do a sanity check
$$a=\log_6(2)\approx 0.386853$$
$$b=\log_5(3)\approx 0.682606$$
$$c=\log_5(2)\approx 0.430677$$
$$\frac{ab}{1-a}\approx\frac{0.386853\times0.682606}{1-0.386853}\approx 0.430676785\dots \approx c$$